# Node aligment: Below

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to align structures %first, %second and %third. I have tried some alignment options using *below* of and *align* but they don't do what I expect.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}




\begin{tikzpicture}
    % First
    \node[fill opacity=0.1,circle,label=left:n1-label,fill=black] at (0,0) (n1) {};
    \node[right=0cm of n1,draw,fill=none, text width=\linewidth-2.4cm] (n2) {
        title2
    };
    \node[below=0.5cm of n2,draw,text width=\linewidth-2.4cm] (n3){
        Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah 
        \blinditemize
    };

    % Second
    \node[below=1cm of n3,fill opacity=0.1,circle,label=left:n4-label,fill=black] at (0,0) (n4) {};
    \node[right=0cm of n4,draw,fill=none, text width=\linewidth-2.4cm] (n5) {
        title2
    };
    \node[below=0.5cm of n5,draw,text width=\linewidth-2.4cm] (n6){
        Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah 
        \blinditemize
    };

    % Third
    \node[below=1cm of n6,fill opacity=0.1,circle,label=left:n7-label,fill=black] at (0,0) (n7) {};
    \node[right=0cm of n7,draw,fill=none, text width=\linewidth-2.4cm] (n8) {
        title3
    };
    \node[below=0.5cm of n8,draw,text width=\linewidth-2.4cm] (n9){
        Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah 
        \blinditemize
    };


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

b) I'd like also to make n2, n3, n5, n6 to span just until the right margin.

Update: Code is been updated with some suggestions, b) is fixed thanks to @marmot

Comment: Absolutely! How can I do that?

Comment: Done. I'm blind! I could not see the mark at the left of the question, I was disabling some add-ons on my browser just to be sure :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FIRST ANSWER**: A few comments:

1. Positioning only works within one `tikzpicture` but not across separate `tikzpicture`s unless you use `overlay`. However, in that case I would not do that.
2. Your syntax `right of=n1` is deprecated, it is not even mentioned in the pgfmanual any more. You greatly benefit from loading the `positioning` library and do something like `right=5mm of n1` instead.
3. If you do not specify the width of the text, the nodes will become arbitrarily wide. In order to avoid this, set an appropriate `text width`.

Suggested code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[buffl/.style={fill opacity=0.1,circle,fill=black}]
\node[buffl,label=left:foo] at (0,0) (n1) {};
\node[draw,fill=none, right=1cm of n1, text width=\linewidth-3.4cm] (n5) {
    title5
};
\node[draw,below=1cm of n5, text width=\linewidth-3.4cm] (n6){
    \blindtext
};
\node[draw,below=1cm of n6, align=center,text width=\linewidth-3.4cm] (n3) {
    \blindtext
};
\node[buffl,label=left:n4-label,left=1cm of n3]  (n4) {};

\draw[fill opacity=0.1] ([yshift=-0.25cm]n1.south) -- ([yshift=0.25cm]n4.north);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**RESPONSE TO YOUR UPDATE**: Given your updated question, I am actually wondering if you would not be better off with a table, and just add the bullets and lines between them via overlay.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{every picture/.append style={remember picture},
fluffy/.style={fill opacity=0.1,circle,fill,inner sep=3pt,outer sep=1mm}}

\blindtext

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} l @{~} |X| @{}}
\cline{2-2}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(l1.base)]
 \node[fluffy,label={[name=l1]left:n1-label}] at (0,0) (n1) {};
\end{tikzpicture}   
& title2\\
\cline{2-2}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{~}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{~}\\
\cline{2-2}
&
 Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah 
 \blinditemize
\\
\cline{2-2}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{~}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{~}\\
\cline{2-2}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(l2.base)]
 \node[fluffy,label={[name=l2]left:n2-label}] at (0,0) (n2) {};
\end{tikzpicture}   
& title2\\
\cline{2-2}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{~}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{~}\\
\cline{2-2}
&
 Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah 
 \blinditemize 
\\
\cline{2-2}
\end{tabularx}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
\draw (n1) -- (n2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks again. I have updated the code with your suggestions. Now, node1 and node 4 are misaligned as they are not in the same tikzpicture. I started to use nodes outside tikzpictures with overlay as I found out I could not access all latex commands and functionality inside the picture and nodes.

Comment: @Rod There is no node 4.

Comment: I updated the code with your suggestions in the first post. It is a repeating structure. The first node of each structure has a line joining it with the first node of the next one.

Comment: @Rod I have not seen your update. I am trying to guess what you might want. (Note that I will be offline now for about 2h.)

Comment: I'll add this to my code. I will need to change some formatting I was using for my titles. Again, thanks for your help @marmot

Comment: Is it possible to align title to label. ie: title2 and n2-label?

Comment: @Rod Yes, with `baseline` (I know you had this in your original code, sorry!) and saying that the base line of the `tikzpicture` should be the baseline of the label. I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest an alternative? I propose to use `tcolorboxes`, they are easily aligned because use the whole textwidth, they can be remembered to draw lines between them, it's possible to add the label with an overlay option, ...

Following first approximation defines two kind of boxes, `mytitle` and `mytext`. `mytitle` boxes use a mandatory parameter which is the `label` for the attached circle. This label will also be the name of nodes. `\mytext` boxes contain the longer text and they can break between pages.

Both kind of nodes can use an optional parameter where it's possible to change colors, distances between previous (`before skip`) or posterior (`after skip`) box, ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\tcbset{
    common/.style={%
        enhanced, sharp corners,
        colback=white, colframe=black,
        notitle, left skip=2.4cm, size = small,
        }
    }

\newtcolorbox{mytitle}[2][]{
    common,
    after skip=5mm, remember,
    overlay={
        \node[fill opacity=.1, fill=black, circle,
            label=left:#2, left=1mm of frame.west] (#2) {};
    },
    #1
}

\newtcolorbox{mytext}[1][]{
    common, breakable,
    #1
}

\begin{document}

\blindtext
\begin{mytitle}{n1-label}
title 2
\end{mytitle}
\begin{mytext}
\blinditemize
\end{mytext}

\begin{mytitle}[before skip=1cm, after skip=2mm, colframe=blue]{n2-label}
title 2
\end{mytitle}
\begin{mytext}
\blinditemize
\end{mytext}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw[shorten >=2mm, shorten <=2mm] (n2-label)--(n1-label);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]